# How to upgrade dtc version in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, upgrade, 18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 when I try to update the package with

> sudo apt-get install device-tree-compiler

it says

> device-tree-compiler is already the newest version (1.4.5-3)

but for [my application](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/meta-zephyr-sdk/releases/tag/0.9.3) it required dtc version to 1.4.6

What should I do in order to get the latest release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download [device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb on AMD64 machines](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/device-tree-compiler/1.4.7-1/+build/15279267/+files/device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb).
2. Double-click device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb to open it for installation in Ubuntu Software or open the terminal and change directories using `cd` to the directory containing device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb and install it with this command:

   ```
   sudo apt install ./device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb
   ```

Comment: link is broken, I used this link instead: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/device-tree-compiler/1.4.7-1/+build/15279267/+files/device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb

Comment: Updated. Thanks for updating the link.