# Upgrading DTC version fails

Tags: apt, upgrade

I tried to use this method to upgrade the DTC version.

```
$ sudo apt install ./device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb
```

The result is disappointing：

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
Note, selecting 'device-tree-compiler' instead of './device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb' 
device-tree-compiler is already the newest version (1.4.7-1). 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
```

```
$ dtc -v
Version: DTC 1.4.0-gf345d9e4
```

I tried [waltinator's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/1157713/),

```
$ sudo dpkg --install ./device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 178854 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking device-tree-compiler (1.4.7-1) over (1.4.7-1) ...
Setting up device-tree-compiler (1.4.7-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

But the version of dtc still not upgraded.

```
$ dtc -v
Version: DTC 1.4.0-gf345d9e4
```

However, when I use this method to view the dtc version, the result is:

```
dpkg -s device-tree-compiler | grep '^Version:'
Version: 1.4.7-1
```

Why is this happening? What could be the issue?

Comment: You haven't linked your question to Ubuntu in any way.  We support Ubuntu (and official flavors) and not generic GNU/Linux.   It's probable the `dtc` version found in your $PATH may not be the version you want?  do you have multiple versions installed?  Please provide the link to Ubuntu in your question.

Comment: I am using this link to improve dtc：https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090223/how-to-upgrade-dtc-version-in-ubuntu-18-04/1157502#1157502

Comment: apt 1.6.11 (amd64)
ubuntu18.04

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `type -a dtc`

Answer (score 1):

`apt` is an interface to the packaging system, and wants package names to install.

The tool to install a `.deb` file is `dpkg`. Read `man dpkg` and do something like:

```
sudo dpkg --install ./device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Using `apt` is also acceptable. See [Braiam's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/769542/816190)

Answer (score 1):

You got this message because you manually downloaded device-tree-compiler_1.4.7-1_amd64.deb and locally installed this .deb file. If you install Synaptic package manager with `sudo apt install synaptic` and check it in *Installed (local or obsolete)* in the left pane it will show that device-tree-compiler is a locally installed package.

device-tree-compiler is in the default repositories of all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. The version of device-tree-compiler in Ubuntu 18.04 is 1.4.5. In Ubuntu 18.10 and later device-tree-compiler 1.4.7 can be installed from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo apt install device-tree-compiler
```